# call on multiple phones - asterisk

Tags: ubuntu, sip, asterisk

I am working on Asterisk. I have a client that has two phones both registers to the server. He wants to receive a call on both phones when someone calls him on one phone. HOw to do that?

Let's say client A has user1 and user2 both registered. When client B calls user1 how can I create the call on user2 phone too? need help. thx

Answer (score 1):

```
exten => _X,1,Dial(SIP/user1&SIP/user2)
```

Answer (score 0):

We generally use ring-all style queues for such situations.